# Создание графических елементов без ui файла

Tags: c++, qt

На что может влиять создание графических элементов без использования `ui` файла?

```
class MainForm : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainForm(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    std::unique_ptr<QLabel> label1;
};
```

Comment: Ни на что. Вы просто не можете открыть ваш виджет в qt designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно говоря, крайне редко используют сами файлы дизайнера для создания форм. Наличие xml файлов в проекте усложняет метаобъектную компиляцию, что в итоге приводит к нужде [собирать проект с нуля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/962852/233158).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тем не менее, дизайнером активно пользуются, но немного по другому. Дизайнер позволяет быстро и правильно спроектировать [компоновку](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) формы, чему активно способствует визуальное отображение и возможность предпросмотра. Так же, если в работе применяют css стили, достаточно удобно видеть изменения в реальном времени и разрабатывать программу "инкрементально".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По завершению успешного проектирования формы в дизайнере, с проверкой работы при разном размером окна с использованием функции предпросмотра, делают автогенерацию кода формы, после он прорабатывается руками и лишь потом идет в саму программу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге получается разделить работу дизайнера и программиста, что позволяет делать современно выглядящие пользовательские интерфейсы относительно быстро. Встроенные в Qt Creator возможности редактирования форм скорее реализуют предпросмотр, чем полноценную замену программы Qt Designer.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]